# How can I trigger a service worker update in Playwright by modifying the HTTP response?

Tags: typescript, service-worker, httpresponse, playwright, end-to-end

I am working on an SPA that I recently added a service worker to, which pre-caches the application shell using a cache-first strategy and caches navigation requests using a network -first strategy.

The SPA contains some logic that displays a "A new version is available!" banner with a "Reload" button at the top of the page when it detects a "waiting" service worker. I would like to write an end-to-end test for this logic and the logic behind the "Reload" button but cannot figure out how to trigger a service worker update in Playwright.

The approach that I have been playing with is modifying the service worker response after the service worker has been installed and a page reload has been triggered. I can modify the response and its response headers but it is not triggering an update event in the browser.

Here is the test code:

```
test("shows an update button when the service worker file has changed", async ({
  page,
  context
}, testInfo) => {
  const newScriptBytes = "/*test*/"
  const timeout = testInfo.timeout
  await page.goto("/")
  await waitForReadyServiceWorker({ context, page, timeout })

  // change the bytes of all additional service worker requests
  await page.route("/service-worker.js", async route => {
    const serverResponse = await page.request.fetch(serviceWorkerUrl, {
      ignoreHTTPSErrors: true
    })
    let serviceWorkerScript = await serverResponse.text()
    serviceWorkerScript = serviceWorkerScript.concat(newScriptBytes)
    await route.fulfill({
      response: serverResponse,
      body: serviceWorkerScript,
      headers: {
        ...serverResponse.headers(),
        "Etag": "v1",
        "Last-Modified": new Date().toUTCString(),
        "Content-Length": serviceWorkerScript.length.toString()
      }
    })
  })

  await page.reload()

  await expect(
    page.locator(`text=A new version is available!`)
  ).toBeVisible()
})

export async function waitForReadyServiceWorker(args: {
  context: BrowserContext
  page: Page
  timeout?: number
}): Promise<Worker | undefined> {
  const timeoutId = createOperationTimeout(args.timeout)
  const url = await args.page.evaluate(async () => {
    const readySw = await navigator.serviceWorker.ready
    return readySw.active.scriptURL
  })
  clearTimeout(timeoutId)
  return args.context.serviceWorkers().find(worker => worker.url() === url)
}
```

Here is the initial service worker response

[image: initial service worker response]

Here is the modified service worker response

[image: modified service worker response]

Comment: That _seems_ like it should trigger an update. You can check the "Application > Service Workers" panel in Chrome's DevTools and see if there's another service worker installed after the code runs, which would help narrow down whether the problem is with a new SW not being installed, or with the code that detects the new installation.

Comment: If you see that the new SW is not being installed at all, you could try switching from `page.reload()` to `page.goto('/')`. A page reload might not trigger the SW update check.

Comment: @JeffPosnick good idea! I have checked for "waiting" service workers in dev tools but only see the currently installed service worker. I have also manually tested the app logic that detects a "waiting" service worker by modifying the script on the local web server after the client has an active service worker, so I know that logic is working. 

I have also tried `page.goto("/")` but that did not trigger a service worker update. Also, I know the service worker update check is being triggered because after `page.reload()` I see a network request for the script (see last image in post).

Comment: It looks like it is [a missing feature](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/14711#issuecomment-1150350107) in Playwright and [a PR](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/pull/14716) is in progress.